# WHERE with two sub conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM conv
WHERE (WHERE from_user = 3 OR to_user = 3)
AND (WHERE conv = 6_3 OR conv = 3_6)
```

So sometimes the `conv` field is in the style `[from_to]` other times it is `[to_from]` depending on who started the conversation. I want to list the messages which were sent by me or to me from the conversation which is either started by me or by the other user towards me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the excess `WHERE`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM conv
WHERE (from_user = 3 OR to_user = 3)
AND (conv = "6_3" OR conv = "3_6")
```

I also wrapped your `conv` values in `"`s, since an `INT` cannot contain an `_`, therefore it must be stored as a `VARCHAR` (and therefore requires `"`s).

Comment: Thanks, I tried everything at one point I nearly got it but it said that it can't find the column 6_3 so by adding the quotes I got it rolling. Thanks Danny. I'll accept your answer in a minute.

Comment: So you've got a column called "conv" in a table called "conv"? And, its content is redundant - it can be calculated from the other columns, which violates 2NF

Comment: I have to agree with @Bohemian; I just posted this as the literal solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM conv
WHERE (from_user = 3 OR to_user = 3)
```

If you want the "Kung Fu" version, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM conv
WHERE 3 IN (from_user, to_user)
```

Comment: hahaaahahahaha "kung fu version" man you can't imagine how tired I'm right now and this made me laugh my ass off :D Sadly none of the versions work in my case. See  Danny's answer. Cheerz mate.

Comment: The kung fu version also means that the database can't use any indexes that happen to be on `from_user` or `to_user`.

Comment: @andy you are 100% correct. I put it out there as a curiosity, but especially because it only uses the variable once, which may be the only solution if there is such a restriction at the caller

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that I thought you would actually use it. :-)  I just mentioned it in case someone else coming along would think it a good way to implement things.

Answer (score 2):

Write `WHERE` keyword once.

```
SELECT * FROM conv WHERE (from_user = 3 OR to_user = 3) AND (conv = 6_3 OR conv = 3_6
```